# is the alert "SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad certificate" indicating the SSL failed

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

while running the below command
openssl s_client -host example.xyz -port 9093

I get the following error.

139810559764296:error:14094412:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad certificate:s3_pkt.c:1259:SSL alert number 42

39810559764296:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:184:

But at the end i get "Verify return code: 0 (ok)" message. My question is what does the above alert signify, and if the SSL was actually successful. Thanks a lot for the help in advance.

### SSL handshake has read 6648 bytes and written 354 bytes

New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-SHA

Server public key is 2048 bit

Secure Renegotiation IS supported

Compression: NONE

Expansion: NONE

SSL-Session:

```
Protocol  : TLSv1.2

Cipher    : AES128-SHA

Session-ID: 57EC2E221A6CDDEDB95F27F826A2CF310010200A645D17F818FB0D35EF4DF12A

Session-ID-ctx:

Master-Key:
```

7C4BA05C349558BAD487B270F74B5040B9FC746A6D15BF2D8E223949E9A1F343A0FED9E154BE53C7
EB52F996C1494101

```
Key-Arg   : None

Krb5 Principal: None

PSK identity: None

PSK identity hint: None

Start Time: 1475096098

Timeout   : 300 (sec)

Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)